# Amenable groupoid C*-algebras satisfy the UCT in English?

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, groupoids, amenability

As is by now well known, Tu proved in 1998 that the C*-algebras coming from amenable groupoids satisfy the so-called UCT (universal coefficient theorem). Unfortunately, I don't speak french and I've only found this result in french.

**Question:** does anyone happen to know of any account of the proof that is written in English?

Tu's original paper is fairly long, and hence would require a lot of work to read for a non-speaker. Even talks available online, or particular cases (such as the same for amenable groups) would be helpful and very much appreciated.

[1] J.L. Tu, *La conjecture de Baum–Connes pour les feuilletages moyennables*, K-Theory **17** (1999) pp. 215–264, ([pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.562.2480&rep=rep1&type=pdf))

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that might see this in the future, in the chapter 12 of [here](https://www.math.ku.dk/english/research/conferences/2017/uct/UCT_Notes_Copenhagen2017.pdf) you may find a short summary of the main ideas of Tu's proof.